# How to respond to django.test.Client using the test database

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-1.9

I have a django `settings.py` file with one configured database, leading to two mysql databases, let's call them `dbname` and `test_dbname`.

When running a command like `python manage.py test ...`, an object selection like

```
MyClass.objects.all()
```

will select the objects from `test_dbname`, so far so good.

On the other hand, if I test the generation of an html page using

```
client = django.test.Client()
response = client.post(...)
```

then the test code (or thread, I'm not sure) that creates the `client` object and the `post` arguments uses `test_dbname` whereas the thread that serves the `post` request and generates the response uses `dbname` (no test_ prepended).

This is an inconvenience, because:

1. My test code can't correctly formulate requests (i.e. post data) if such requests should depend on the server thread's database, leading to problems like [How to test a Django form with a ModelChoiceField using test client and post method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034938/)
2. There are now TWO databases under test, whereas the contents of only one of them seems to be controllable from my test code, which makes the tests unpredictable.

Can I make the server thread use a database that I can control from the test case thread?

Comment: The test client does not use a separate thread like a WSGI server would. It simply directly calls the relevant Django functions that would otherwise respond to a WSGI request. If queries are referring to the wrong database, you are most likely executing queries before the test database has been set up.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that seems to have solved it, will describe situation below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to knbk for the hint that solved this: The answer is that no queries should be run before the unit tests start. In my case this meant replacing a form definition like

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=<somequery>)
```

which ran `somequery` upon importing the file, i.e. before the test cases ran, by:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_field = forms.ChoiceField()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['my_field'].choices = <somequery>
```